# How to get list of declared exchanges and queues in rabbitmq using Java?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am looking for a way to list all declared exchanges, queues in rabbitmq using Java code.
I do know that command "rabbitmqctl  list_queues" also I am aware of "rabbitmqadmin list queues"

Answer (score 11):

You can use the HTTP API.

Install the web-management plug-in:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

then use the API to get the informations:

```
http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges
http://localhost:15672/api/queues
```

The full API list is available on:

```
http://localhost:15672/api/
```

Just execute an java http request and get the json result.

Comment: Very helpful and easy. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to get the list of exchanges or queues into a `JComboBox`. Didn't use `JSON` parser, just used `split` function... Good luck

```
private void getValuesFromRabbitWebAPI(String strURL, JComboBox<String> c) throws MalformedURLException, IOException 
{

    String loginPassword = username()+ ":" + password();
    String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(loginPassword.getBytes());

    URL url = new URL(strURL);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
    String response = "";
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            response += line;
        }
    }
    String[] split = response.split("\"name\":\"");
    c.addItem((String)"");
    // skipping the first element "[{" or ""
    for(int i=1; i<split.length; i++)
    {
        String nameRaw = split[i];
        int index = nameRaw.indexOf("\"");
        if (index > 0 && !nameRaw.startsWith("amq."))
        {
            String name = nameRaw.substring(0, index);
            c.addItem((String) name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters to the function to get exchanges:

```
getValuesFromRabbitWebAPI("http://" + hostname + ":15672/api/exchanges", exchangeComboBox);
```

or to get the queues:

```
getValuesFromRabbitWebAPI("http://" + hostname + ":15672/api/queues", queueComboBox);
```